# mode rewrite redirecting directory to another wont work

Tags: mod-rewrite

alright so i have a need for mode rewrite and i am completely noob/new to it.

I've read sever guide. that explained mode rewrite goes - pattern - redirection - flags.

i am trying to redirect anyone that gets into `domain.com/product/ to domain.com/product.php`
and pass the variable url=232 however i am first trying to redirect /product/ to product.php

Here is what i got so far.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \/product\/ /product.php
```

I've started even more basic then that by redirect `product.php to index.php` and that worked.

am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^product/?$ /product.php?url=232
```

Comment: zerkms will that redirect url=232 specific ?

Comment: @Neta Meta: I don't get what you mean

Comment: it wont pass the 232 as a variable

Comment: @Neta Meta: why do you think so? I definitely will do that.

Comment: Thanks zerkms, i am probably doing something wrong but it didnt redirect. i will continue readying maybe i am missing something.

Comment: @Neta Meta: are you sure your `.htaccess` is even parsed? What if you put "my .htaccess isn't parsed" string in any place in `.htaccess`?

Comment: the `?url=232` is a query string (`$_GET`) parameter which will set `$_GET['url'] == '232'` for *product.php*

Comment: @Zerkms Putting that return an error, and i think i it does because when i tried redirecting to index page it works. Zach L yea i know

Comment: @Neta Meta: you've lost me. My rewrite rule works and does exactly what you asked. That's it.